Get data from 3 tables using single query
I have 3 tables in a MySQL database
user
user_id, (PK)
email
agreement_user
agreement_user_id, (PK)
user_id, (FK user.user_id)
details
contract
contract_id, (PK)
agreement_user_id, (FK agreement_user.agreement_user_id)
details
What should be the query to get contract.details and user.email given a contract_id

maybe you can try
SELECT contract.details, user.email FROM contract
INNER JOIN agreement_user ON contract.agreement_user_id = agreement_user.agreement_user_id
INNER JOIN user ON agreement_user.user_id = user.user_id
WHERE contract.contract_id = @yourSpecificId;


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Try this
   SELECT u.email, c.details FROM contract AS co
   JOIN agreement_user AS au ON co.agreement_user_id = au.agreement_user_id
   JOIN user AS u ON au.user_id = u.user_id
   WHERE co.contract_id = @contractId

Replace @contractId with your value
